# React Helmet MIME type issue

Tags: reactjs, react-helmet

I am using React helmet to add external scripts to my react app.

```
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";
<Helmet>
<script src="/path/to/resource.js" type="text/javascript" />
</Helmet>
```

This is giving an error The resource from “http://localhost:3000/%PUBLIC_URL%/js/resource.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: Have you checked the path in console/network tab to see if it's a 404 not found error? Sometimes, 404 error causes this behavior. I don't think this has anything to do with Helmet

Comment: @the.marolie if its a 404 error then does that mean the file is not found in the public folder? I have the js file in the public/js folder

Comment: It normally means file not found. But that does not mean that the file does not exist in the folder, it's just that the path is incorrect. Maybe you're public folder path is incorrect. What is the path that you are specifying ?

Comment: @the.marolie my path is <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/resource.js/>

Comment: what about in console when you hover over the js file? Is that link correct? Maybe try `<script src="/%PUBLIC_URL%/js/resource.js/>`

Comment: @the.marolie ,added / and still same issue.